# How can I compile some LaTeX source into PDF and keep the LaTeX source as some meta-information in the PDF?

Tags: pdf, compiling

How can I compile some LaTeX source into PDF and keep the LaTeX source as some meta-information in the PDF? (or somehow embedded otherwise in the way that it is easy to retrieve the LaTeX source while having the option not to view it when reading the PDF)

Comment: you can use the packages embedfile or attachfile2

Comment: See also package `embedall`.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit of a hack, but you can edit pdf files directly. If it was a short amount of text, you can just open the pdf file in a text editor such as vim and write a comment, e.g.  "%This file was written by Batman". However, that wouldn't be generated every time you compile the latex document.

An alternative could be to add something to a makefile (if you are using a makefile to compile the document) that appends the string you want to the output pdf file.

Comment: You will break the xref table (and with it the pdf) if you do this. You can only replace bytes not add some.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for pointing that out. It might work if the pdf was produced with >= v1.6 which doesn't use an xref table (although, it might still break).  One can force pdflatex to produce a pdf with v1.7 with "\pdfminorversion=7".

Comment: sorry? Where in the reference do you find that there is no xref in newer pdf? If you had tried and looked you would have found the startxref entry with the byte offset at the end of the pdf.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I think it should be possible to add comments after the trailer.  That does not change the byte offsets.